# Lambda to call incoming webhooks

Tags: python, aws-lambda, webhooks, aws-step-functions

I have been using a bash script to call a webhook that trigger azure devops pipeline, now want to use lambda function to do the same thing but am having issue with identation.

```
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
        import subprocess
        result = subprocess.call("curl -X POST 'https://dev.azure.com/organisation/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/stepfunction?api-version=6.0-preview' -d '{ "tags2": {} }' -H "Content-Type: application/json"", shell=True)
        return result
```

The error is below and am not sure why is not working. Any idea why?

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: c750f682-5f80-4ab1-9ef1-7cac25878b11 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 3)
```

Trying this now and comes up with :

```
import json
from urllib import request, parse
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    some_url = "https://dev.azure.com/organization/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/stepfunction?api-version=6.0-preview"
    some_data = {"tags":[]}
    result = do_post(some_url,some_data)
    return {"statusCode":200,body:"sent callback"}
```

But the error comes up :

```
[ERROR] NameError: name 'do_post' is not defined
```

Comment: you have all kinds of messed up quotes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you mixing linux curl with python? ... just use python

```
def do_post(url,data):
    from urllib import request, parse
    data_str = json.dumps(data).encode()
    headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    req =  request.Request(url, headers=headers,data=data_str) # this will make the method "POST"
    resp = request.urlopen(req)
    return resp

resp = do_post('https://dev.azure.com/organisation/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/stepfunction?api-version=6.0-preview',{"tags":[]})
```

something like that

of coarse in a lambda fn you would need to set it up appropriately...

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    some_url = "https://..."
    some_data = {"key":"value"}
    result = do_post(some_url,some_data)
    return {"statusCode":200,body:"sent callback"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joran. It is complaining about  "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",

Comment: how do I define the do_post. When I define the do_post, is also complaining about lambda_function.   any reason for this error. I edit my question to include the code : [ERROR] NameError: name 'do_post' is not defined